# Why is the Promise api call not delivering the correct data elements?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, promise

I have the following service method:

```
public getConf() : Promise<string[]> {
let rows : string[] = [];

  this.dao.getData(SearchCriteria.getRecordsFrom("EcegConfig")).then(configs => {
    configs.forEach((cfg : EcegConfRecord) => {
      console.log("START", cfg.data.ecegconf);
      let tmp = cfg.data.ecegconf;
      rows.push(tmp);
    });
  });

return of(rows).toPromise();}
```

and the following code block in my component in ngOnInit():

```
 this.http.getConf().then(data => {
  console.log("D A T A", data, data.length, data[0]);
});
```

I can see the correct strings in data, **but length is 0 and data[0] is undefined** and I can't use forEach on data.
Also the START console.log gives me the correct string items.

(I know its maybe unusual that I used return of(rows).toPromise(), I just started with an Observable output, but that should not be the error or? I'm using this in some other methods and it works as intended there)

As I understood the Promise the .then() waits until the return of the service method is complete, or? so data should have elements within it or? So I have maybe a type error somewhere? (But as I said START delivers a correct string and this is the only thing I'm pushing into rows. so Promise return type should be ok or?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's annotate the code with the time where each line is executed:

```
public getConf() : Promise<string[]> {
  let rows : string[] = []; // t0

  this.dao.getData(SearchCriteria.getRecordsFrom("EcegConfig")) // t1
    .then(configs => {
      // t10000
      configs.forEach((cfg : EcegConfRecord) => {
        console.log("START", cfg.data.ecegconf);
        let tmp = cfg.data.ecegconf;
        rows.push(tmp);
      });
    });

  return of(rows).toPromise(); // t2
}
```

The whole point of a promise or observable is to be able to register a callback that will be called *asynchronously*, when the response of the http request is finally available, at time `t10000`. But you create an observable which emits your empty array immediately and transform it to a promise. So that can't work.

I would stop using promises and embrace observables, because they're inevitable anyway in Angular, and are more powerful than promises. All you would need if `getData` returned an observable would be

```
return this.dao.getData(SearchCriteria.getRecordsFrom("EcegConfig")).pipe(
  map(configs => configs.map((cfg : EcegConfRecord) => cfg.data.ecegconf))
);
```

If you really want to keep using promises, you can just use

```
return this.dao.getData(SearchCriteria.getRecordsFrom("EcegConfig")).then(
  configs => configs.map((cfg : EcegConfRecord) => cfg.data.ecegconf)
);
```